# Applying a keyboard macro to an active region in Emacs

Tags: emacs, macros

I am trying to learn to use keyboard macros more but wasn't sure how to approach this.

I need to select a region, then run two query-replacements on that region. The region will be different each time, but the query replacements will be the same.

The problem comes because the first query replace (or `replace-string`) removes the active region.  If I use <kbd>C-u C-SPC</kbd>, it appears the beginning mark is saved, but the point is not saved, so the active region is not available for the second replace operation.

How can I apply two operations, which remove the active region as a side effect, to the same region in a keyboard macro?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As I don't perfom tasks like the one described that often I'm not sure I can advice you the quickest solution but here at least two approaches that will work.

### Option 1

This option involves using *narrowing* to reduce the buffer to the active region prior to performing query-replace, or whatever you want to do with the region. The workflow would be as follows:

- ... start recording your keyboard macro with region active
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> narrow-to-region
- ... perform the operations you want to perform happily jumping back to the start via  <kbd>M-<</kbd> (beginning-of-buffer) and the like
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> widen
- ... stop recording your keyboard macro

You should be able to happily apply it to any highlighted region.

BTW: narrow-to-region and widen have a default bindings of  <kbd>C-x n n</kbd> (narrow-to-region) and <kbd>C-x n w</kbd> (widen) so you could use them either in case you haven't changed your keybindings

### Option 2

This options involves using *registers* to store the locations of the region prior to "destroying" it. The actual workflow would look like

- ... start recording your keyboard macro with region active
- <kbd>C-x r SPC</kbd> 1  (point-to-register)
- <kbd>C-x C-x</kbd>  (exchange-point-and-mark)
- <kbd>C-x r SPC</kbd> 2 (point-to-register)
- ... perform the operation that "destroys" the region
- <kbd>C-x r j</kbd> 2 (jump-to-register)
- <kbd>C-SPC</kbd>
- <kbd>C-x r j</kbd> 1 (jump-to-register)
- ... now your region should be back again, so happily apply any other operations not "destroying" the region
- ... stop recording your keyboard macro

Comment: Two great tips, thanks.  I think what I was missing was `point-to-register`, but I think that  narrow-to-region and widen will be really useful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is `exchange-point-and-mark` <kbd>C-x C-x</kbd>.  This has
the effect of re-activating the mark.

Comment: Unfortunately that alone won't do it, as the problem is the point from where the search started is "lost". As the region is the part between point and mark C-xC-x will not restore the original region. Possibly there is another way to restore the original position of point - maybe because it is pushed on some mark-ring or anything prior to destroying it by starting to move point by performing query-replace. If you know of such a trick please let us know.